# How to isolate jQuery each() to a starting element's parent container's children

Tags: jquery, each

In the script below, I need to alter the jQuery each() so that instead of using the generic classes, it starts at a target element, #customfield_11071, then crawls up to the nearest "active-pane" parent element (.active-pane#tab-5) and passes only the child element inputs with class="text.long-field" to the each?

I thought that by passing the #tab-5 directly to the each it would do it, but its picking up text input fields matching the class outside of the tab-5 parent container and adding those to the total, resulting in a bad calculation.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
        //handler to trigger sum event
        jQuery("#tab-5 input.text.long-field").each(function() {

            jQuery(this).keyup(function(){
                calculateSum();
            });
        });

    });

    function calculateSum() {

        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        jQuery("#tab-5 input.text.long-field").each(function() {

            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0 && this.id !== "customfield_11071") {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }

        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        jQuery("#customfield_11071").val(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
```

HTML

```
  <div class="tabs-pane active-pane" id="tab-5">
    <div class="field-group">
      <label for="customfield_12370">
        Test Case Estimate
      </label>
      <input class="text long-field" id="customfield_12370" name="customfield_12370" type="text" value="">
      <div class="description">
        Will hold all QA estimates for Test Case preparation/creation efforts.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-group">
      <label for="customfield_12371">
        Test Analysis Estimate
      </label>
      <input class="text long-field" id="customfield_12371" name="customfield_12371" type="text" value="">
      <div class="description">
        Will hold all QA estimates for testing analysis efforts.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-group">
      <label for="customfield_11071">
        QA Estimate Total
      </label>
      <input class="text long-field" id="customfield_11071" name="customfield_11071" type="text" value="">
      <div class="description">
        Estimated LOE in Hours
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

UPDATE: Alternately, rather than passing the class string to the each, perhaps I can populate the specific collection of ids into an array and pass that to the each()?

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){` doesn't make sense. The `ready` handler is passed the jQuery object so that you can declare it how you would like. Having them the same defeats that purpose.

Comment: `"..its picking up text input fields matching the class outside of the tab-5 parent.."`, no it is'nt! Something else must be going on, as it would'nt select elements outside `#tab-5` with that selector ?

Comment: You can provide a context to jQuery selectors: `$('input:text', '#tab-5')`. Then you'd be absolutely sure it wasn't selecting anything outside of it.

Comment: Seems to work as is ... http://jsfiddle.net/jEEKL/

Comment: @adeneo, perhaps he has a duplicate id?

Comment: @JeffPaquette - Then it would only get the first instance of that ID, not multiple elements with the same ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script works fine in isolation. See http://jsfiddle.net/jEEKL/ . If you're getting extra fields with this `jQuery("#tab-5 input.text.long-field")` jQuery selector, check your source for duplicate tab ids.

Comment: Thanks. I found the problem was a duplicate ID.